# What is the probability that price reaches expected target within a time interval?

Tags: probability, finance, discrete-time

#### The Forecasting Model

I have developed a proprietary forecasting model (call it AMA) that forecasts an expected **range** in price movement of a particular security. An example of the way it works is by giving out expected price range movement of $\mathrm{$10}$ for a $\mathrm{$100}$ stock within the next hour (or any given time interval or period).

For an overview using the above example, we'll ignore the possibility of the stock's price falling and focus only on price rising to avoid over-complicating things.

In the model, a stock's current high price $H_{t_i}$, is forecasted to print a price high by adding the Differential High $DH_t$ to the previous period's closing price, $C_{(t-1)}$, giving us $E(H_{t})$.

Let 
$t_i=$ $\mathrm{1\,hour\,period}$, divided into 10 sub intervals where $i=$ $\mathrm{1,2,3,...,10}$ 
$C_{t_i}$ = $\mathrm{Current\,price\,in\,period}$ $t$
$H_{t_i}$ = $\mathrm{Current\,high\,price\,in\,period}$ $t$
$DH_t$ = $\mathrm{Differential\,High}$
$C_{(t-1)}$ = $\mathrm{Previous\,closing\,price}$
$E(H_{t})$ = $C_{(t-1)}+DH_t$; $\mathrm{AMA\,/\,Expected\,high\,price\,of\,current\,period}$

Assume $C_{t_i}$= $H_t$ for this problem.

### The Problem

However, I'm having confusion in calculating the probability that price reaches $100\%$ AMA before the time interval ends, whether to use Bayes Theorem or Poisson. I have a basic understanding of probability so Poisson is a bit out of my domain.

Intuitively though, the probability of reaching $E(H_{t})$ should diminish/reduce over time the closer we get to an hour's time given that $H_t=c$, where c is a fixed constant price throughout the period (stagnant). Conversely, this would also imply that the probability of reaching $E(H_{t})$ increases when $H_t$ moves closer to the expected high price.

## Test Solutions

The way I tried to solve the question is by constructing a counting table to compute the probability. However I am not confident of my probability test calculations given the nature of time decay of the problem (which sounds a lot like Poisson). However, the thought process makes sense intuitively as I have mentioned above given the calculations I did which is prone to error.

A snippet of my calculations in the picture below is constructed behind the premise of basic probability where $$P(A)=\frac{number\,of\,favourable\,outcomes}{total\,number\,of\,outcomes}$$
$$A = \mathrm{Event\,of\,reaching\,100\%\,AMA\,occuring}$$

---

[Test Solution #1: "Modified" Basic Probability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnFiy.png)

The confirmation bias is strong with this solution as it's not mathematically sound ie. I manipulated the formula to make it display increasing probability of event $A$ occurring when $H_{t_i}$ increases towards $100\%$ AMA within a time interval whereas decreasing probability as $H_{t_i}$ remains the same throughout the whole period $t_{1,2,...10}$. Regardless, I'm describing the formula anyways.
$P(A)=1-\frac{number\,of\,favourable\,outcomes}{total\,number\,of\,outcomes}$

---

[Test Solution #2: Basic Probability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArgYu.png)

This one is mathematically sound and doesn't involve any manipulation to fit my presumptions where the formula is the basic probability calculation as described earlier. However intuitively, this doesn't make any sense as it assumes that the probability of event $A$ occurring is the same given AMA =$10\%,20\%,\,...,100\%\,for\,t_{1,2,3,...,10}$

---

[Test Solution #3: Hybrid 1D Random Walk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9InyH.png)

Note the Random Walk model in this one is only possible with movements north or east outwards along y- and x-axis respectively due to the time decay nature of the problem. In this one, it assumes that since there are only 2 possible outcomes for each node, the probability is $50\%$ chance for the price to either reach a new AMA high along the y-axis or exhausting the time interval to move on to the next node along the x-axis where $H_{t_i}=c$.

---

#### Final Notes

Given all the Test Solutions I've presented, how do I determine the correct one to use (as a starting point) so as to develop a working probability model for this problem?

TLDR version: I need to find a viable solution to calculating the probability that price reaches the AMA or Expected High before the time interval ends. 3 Test Solutions are given and which one is the correct one (if any) to base off of to repair this probability model?